# Is there a way to implement normal anchor function when using JQuery BBQ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-bbq

Just that - or alternatively, is there another easy enough way to load content in one div/etc without reloading another? & with back, bookmark, & anchor functionality?

Thanks

addon: OR - is there an alternative way to 'scroll to a point' using some jquery/javascript sorcery? so that I could use JQuery BBQ AND the jquery/javascript scrolling?

I just need to get this done.